# Is there any good book on history of the heresy of Modernism?

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, heresy

Is there any good book on the history of the heresy of [Modernism](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/10415a.htm) ([=synthesis of all heresies](http://w2.vatican.va/content/pius-x/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-x_enc_19070908_pascendi-dominici-gregis.html))? I am interested in how modernism came to be and how it survived [St. Pius X](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/12137a.htm) attack on it. It would be good to have a detailed account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good introduction to the history and philosophy of Modernism:

- Dominique Bourmaud, [*One Hundred Years of Modernism: A History of Modernism, Aristotle to the Second Vatican Council*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=8567) (Kansas City, Mo.: Angelus Press, 2006).
  <sub>e-book en español: [*Cien años de Modernismo: Genealogia del Concilio Vaticano II*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6921)</sub>

## History

- Emile Poulat, [*Histoire, dogme et critique dans la crise moderniste*](https://www.worldcat.org/title/histoire-dogme-et-critique-dans-la-crise-moderniste/oclc/23418212) (Tournai, Belgium: Casterman, 1962).
  <sub>e-book in italiano: [*Storia, dogma, e critica nella crisi modernista*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=4361)</sub>
- Romano Amerio, [*Iota Unum: A Study of Changes in the Catholic Church in the XX<sup>th</sup> Century*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=9424) (Kansas City, MO: Sarto House, 1996).
  <sub>e-book en español: [*Iota Unum: Estudio sobre las transformaciones de la Iglesia Católica en el siglo XX*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6748)</sub>
- Alexander Roper Vidler, [*A Variety of Catholic Modernists*](https://www.worldcat.org/title/variety-of-catholic-modernists/oclc/661014047) (Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, 2009).

## Doctrine

- Jean Baptiste Lemius and John Fitzpatrick, [*Catechism on Modernism According to the Encyclical “Pascendi Dominici Gregis” of His Holiness Pius X*](https://archive.org/details/catechismonmoder00lemiuoft) (London: R. & T. Washbourne, 1908).
  <sub>Fr. Lemius is the presumed drafter of Pope St. Pius X's encyclical on Modernism, [*Pascendi*](https://w2.vatican.va/content/pius-x/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-x_enc_19070908_pascendi-dominici-gregis.html).</sub>
- Thomas Joseph Walshe, *[The Principles of Catholic Apologetics : A Study of Modernism Based Chiefly on the Lectures of Père Garrigou-Lagrange “De Revelatione per Ecclesiam Catholicam Proposita” Adapted and Re-Arranged](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=3024)* (Eugene, Or.: Wipf & Stock Publishers, 2009).
- Jürgen Mettepenningen, [*Nouvelle Théologie - New Theology: Inheritor of Modernism, Precursor of Vatican II*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=3035) (London; New York: T & T Clark, 2010).
  <sub>The "New Theology" is [neo-Modernism](https://iteadthomam.blogspot.com/2010/09/modernism-vs-neo-modernism-what-is.html); Pope Pius XII condemned it in his 1950 encyclical [*Humani Generis*](https://w2.vatican.va/content/pius-xii/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-xii_enc_12081950_humani-generis.html), subtitled: "concerning some false opinions threatening to undermine the foundations of Catholic doctrine." It's drafter is thought to have been Fr. Réginald Garrigou-Lagrange, O.P, ∵ he wrote "[The structure of the encyclical *Humani Generis*](http://scholastic.us.to/hg_gl.html)." Cf. also: Greenstock, David L., T.O.P., "[Thomism and the New Theology](http://modernism.us.to/Thomism%20and%20the%20New%20Theology%20(Greenstock).pdf)," [*The Thomist*](http://www.thomist.org/jourl/explore.htm), 13 (1950), p. 567 & [this quote from it re: theological conclusions](https://iteadthomam.blogspot.com/2010/09/god-revealing-man-to-himself-nouvelle.html).</sub>

## [Key Magisterial Documents](http://modernism.us.to/)

- Pope St. Pius X, [*Pascendi Dominici Gregis*](https://w2.vatican.va/content/pius-x/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-x_enc_19070908_pascendi-dominici-gregis.html) & [Syllabus of Errors, *Lamentabili Sane*](http://www.papalencyclicals.net/Pius10/p10lamen.htm) (1907), [Oath Against Modernism](https://www.papalencyclicals.net/Pius10/p10moath.htm) (1910)
- Pope Pius XII, [*Humani Generis*](https://w2.vatican.va/content/pius-xii/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-xii_enc_12081950_humani-generis.html) (1950)

Comment: To add two good lectures that I found by William H. Marshner: [Modernism In The Church Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVS-kOW6eM8) and [Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Of1zMRtALLQ)

Comment: @Thom Thanks. I'd never heard of Marshner before. His lectures seem good. I see he also wrote [_Defending the Faith: An Anti-Modernist Anthology_](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7379) (2017).

Comment: @Thom [Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Of1zMRtALLQ) @ circa 52 min. is interesting because he discusses how Blondel sought to argue philosophically that man needs the supernatural. This is quite different from saying one can argue philosophically for the existence of the supernatural order; cf. pt. 2 ch. 1 of [_Sense of Mystery_](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6905) by Garrigou-Lagrange, O.P.

Comment: @Thom Thanks! Happy feast to you, too ([arguably the greatest Marian feast](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/71921/1787)). ☺