# Is it more Participatio Actuosa if the congregation hears the words of the Consecration?

Tags: catholicism, mass

I have a question on Participatio Actuosa. This is a term that makes a lot of people confused.
Anyway, in the EF of the Roman rite the Priest says the words of the Consecration in silence. He is the only one who can hear him saying the words. In the OF the Priest says the words so that we all (unless you are deaf) can hear him. There seems to be a new teaching here. If you hear the words than you are participating more. Nowadays you should hear almost everything the Priest says. I don't know why this is.

Is it more Participatio Actuosa if the congregation hears the words of the Consecration?

Answer (score -1):

## "Active participation" means participating in the prayer of the Mass.

"Active participation" originally meant the congregation participating in the priest's sacrifice, especially by singing the Gregorian chant (cf. Pope St. Pius X, [*Tra le sollecitudini*](https://adoremus.org/1903/11/tra-le-sollecitudini/)).

## The words of consecration must not be said in a loud voice.

The [Council of Trent, Session 22, *Doctrina de ss. Missae sacrificio*, 17 September 1562](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/creeds2.v.i.i.ix.html) [anathematizes](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=31797) those who think

> [Canon IX](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/creeds2.v.i.i.ix.html#v.i.i.ix-p14.84).— […] that the rite of the Roman Church, according to which a part of the canon and the words of consecration are pronounced in a low tone [*submissa voce*], is to be condemned; or, that the mass ought to be celebrated in the vulgar tongue only

It also says ([Chapter V. *On the solemn ceremonies of the Sacrifice of the Mass.*](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/creeds2.v.i.i.ix.html#v.i.i.ix-p10.37)) that

> holy Mother Church instituted certain rites, to wit, that certain things be pronounced in the mass in a low [*summissa*], and others in a louder [*elatiore*], tone [*voce*].

This teaching was also taught by Pope Pius VI in his bull [*Auctorem Fidei*](http://www.churchmilitant.tv/cia/05rebellion/12.pdf) condemning the heretical [Council of Pistoia](http://rorate-caeli.blogspot.com/2006/03/liturgical-stake.html) [[DZ 15](http://denzinger.patristica.net/denzinger/#n1500)33]:

> The proposition of the [heretical] synod [of Pistoia:] […] "[…] by expressing it [the liturgy] in the vernacular language, by uttering it in a loud voice"; […]—rash, offensive to pious ears, insulting to the Church, favorable to the charges of heretics against it.

Comment: active? Is that really good Latin? I am no expert in Latin so I have to ask. I have heard it being translated as "actual"

Comment: so back in the 16th century you were considered a bad person if you wanted Mass in the vernacular?

Comment: @andrewjohnsson Pope St. Pius X wrote that encyclical [in Italian](http://www.vatican.va/content/pius-x/it/motu_proprio/documents/hf_p-x_motu-proprio_19031122_sollecitudini.html) (the title is Italian, not Latin); he uses "_partecipazione attiva_" (active participation). Also, the Council of Pistoia was condemned in 1794.

Comment: Canon IX seems to say that saying that Mass should not be celebrated in the vernacular is ok but saying that Mass should only be celebrated in the varnacular is bad. I guess I missunderstand. I am not sure Catholics today are allowed to say that Mass should never be celebrated in the vernacular.

Comment: @andrewjohnsson Because they're [Modernists](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/72030/1787), and Modernists think Catholic dogma can change. There are faithful Catholic priests who say the pre-Vatican II, Catholic Mass, and Catholic laity who assist at such Masses; see the [WikiMissa](https://www.wikimissa.org/yeswiki/?PagePrincipale) directory to find one in your area.

Comment: Who are you refering to when you say modernists?  Sure there are Priests who are in good standing with the Church who say the EF.

Comment: @andrewjohnsson Those who say the Mass entirely in the vernacular, which is against the Council of Trent; cf. [Cdl. Ottaviani's intervention to Paul VI on September 25th, 1969](https://www.ewtn.com/catholicism/library/letter-from-cardinal-ottaviani-to-his-holiness-pope-paul-vi-rome-september-25th-1969-2473).